# Hosting Nancy on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mono, nancy

I'm having trouble getting a nancy site running on Ubuntu 14.04

If I make a simple nancy asp.net site that works on Windows as well as in Monodevelop xps4 debugger, I cant get it running under Apache2 with Mod_mono.

I can however get a normal web forms (.aspx pages) site running on Apache.
I have also followed the example https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-Nginx-on-Ubuntu and that does not run Ubuntu/ NginX either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `I cant get it running` is not detailed enough for stackoverflow, please tell us what is the exact problem, does it throw an error? does it hang? also, tell us the version of mono you're using

Comment: I just setup nancyfx on Ubuntu 14 following the nginx example, it works fine. Please add more info.